# Projection queries with zigzag merge

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I would like to use projection queries on AppEngine together with zigzag merge. It appears that this requires the projected property to be included in every index used by the zigzag merge query. In my use case this would result in entity update costs which are too high.

To illustrate, below is a simple example using the Java low-level Datastore API and using the indices Index(E, p1, p3) and Index(E, p2, p3); this works but duplicates the p3 property of entity E in the two indices.

```
// Create a sample entity with three (indexed) properties.
DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
Entity e = new Entity("E");
e.setProperty("p1", 1);
e.setProperty("p2", 1);
e.setProperty("p3", 1);
datastore.put(e);

// Query for the above entity with a projection on property p3.
Query q = new Query("E");
Filter filter1 = new FilterPredicate("p1", FilterOperator.EQUAL, 1);
Filter filter2 = new FilterPredicate("p2", FilterOperator.EQUAL, 1);
q.setFilter(CompositeFilterOperator.and(filter1, filter2));
q.addProjection(new PropertyProjection("p3", Integer.class));
PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(q);
pq.asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withDefaults());
```

I'd like to remove one of the composite indices, say Index(E, p2, p3), and just rely on the default index for property p2, thus reducing update costs. But doing so results in a DatastoreNeedIndexException at runtime.

Note that a similar problem occurs if I keep the above two indices but add a fourth property to only one of them and include this fourth property in the projection. The use of a default index therefore does not seem to be the problem.

So my question: is there any way of doing projection queries with zigzag merge without duplicating all the projected properties across indices? If not, I'd like to understand what the underlying technical reason is.

Any pointers greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I now see why the projected property needs to be duplicated in all involved indices: because the index sort order has to be the same in all relevant index blocks (two in this example) for zigzag merge to work.

In the example, the last sort order is done on the projected property. When this index is removed it changes the sort order, and a new sort of indexes would be needed for it to work.

So, I don't think what I'm after is possible on AppEngine at the moment. A new dedicated AppEngine feature would be required to enable indexed properties that do not affect index sort order.